# Saving position of drag and drop in javascript into a text or excel file?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, text, javascript-objects

Hi guys I've been working on this project that saves the position of the drag and drop and i was wondering if there is away to save is position to a text or excel file giving you the time of the move.

i.e   DIV 1 was moved to A at 09:00, DIV 1 was moved from A to B at 09:15 if that makes sense.

Couldn't figure it out.

```
<html>
<head>
<\head>

<style>
#draggable1 {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;

margin: 1px 0;
padding: 0 20px;
height: 20px;
width: 50px;
line-height: 20px;
border-radius: 1px;
background: #136a8a;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);
color: #fff;
list-style: none;
}


.draggable {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
padding: 0.5em;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#draggable,
#draggable2 {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#draggable {
cursor: n-resize;
}

#draggable3 {
cursor: move;
}

#containment-wrapper {
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 5px;
}

h3 {
clear: left;
}




#box {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #ccc;
}
<\style>


<body>
<ul class="drag-sort-enable">
<li0 id="draggable1" class="draggable ui-widget-content" input type="text" >659451</li0>
</body>`



<script>
var sPositions = localStorage.positions || "{}",
positions = JSON.parse(sPositions);
$.each(positions, function(id, pos) {
$("#" + id).css(pos)
})
$("#draggable1").draggable({
containment: "#containment-wrapper",
scroll: false,
stop: function(event, ui) {
positions[this.id] = ui.position
localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
}
});

<\script>
```

Comment: the big question is where you want to save it. Client-sided or server-sided. If you do it user-sided then you're more or less limited to the Browser Storage. If you need it to work acrrosss multiple users and browsers then you need a database and a sever-sided solution.

Comment: Yes I'm looking server side, because there will be multiple users on different devices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.